# Votes discrepancy between profile summary page and detail page.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've just noticed that my list of votes cast shows 601 votes, whereas my summary page shows 618.

Summary:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10832/max-vernon
[image]

Details:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10832/max-vernon?tab=votes
[image]

Is this "expected behavior"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is my understanding that as questions are deleted, or in some other cases, the questions you vote for still show in the one list but are obviously no longer counted in the other.

Good catch, but as far as I am aware, this is "the way it is supposed to work". I'll get confirmation if I can in the form of a [Meta meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) link.

[Different Value of Votes in Profile Page (Summary Tab vs. Votes Tab)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146668/different-value-of-votes-in-profile-page-summary-tab-vs-votes-tab)

Comment: Yep, the totals include deleted content (since downvoted stuff is often deleted, and we'd cheat you on that count otherwise most of the time)

Comment: Thanks Nick! </fluff>